# What's the right way to implement sortable table with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My current implementation:

```
export const SORT_ORDER = {
    ASC: "ascending",
    DESC: "descending",
    OTHER: "other"
};

export default class Table extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.sortIcon = new Map();
        this.sortIcon.set(SORT_ORDER.ASC, sortAsc);
        this.sortIcon.set(SORT_ORDER.DESC, sortDesc);
        this.sortIcon.set(SORT_ORDER.OTHER, sortOther);

        this.state = {
            sortField: this.props.defaultSortColumn,
            sortOrder: this.props.defaultSortOrder
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.sort(this.props.defaultSortColumn, this.props.defaultSortOrder)();
    }

    retrieveOrder = (columnId) => {
        return columnId === this.state.sortField ? this.state.sortOrder : SORT_ORDER.OTHER;
    };

    nextOrder = (current) => {
        if (current === SORT_ORDER.DESC) {
            return SORT_ORDER.ASC;
        } else if (current === SORT_ORDER.ASC) {
            return SORT_ORDER.DESC;
        } else {
            return this.props.defaultSortOrder;
        }
    };

    sort = (columnId, order) => () => {
        let descriptor = this.props.structure[columnId];
        let values = this.props.value.slice();

        let orderFactor = order === SORT_ORDER.ASC ? 1 : -1;
        values.sort((a, b) => {
            let first = descriptor.render(a);
            let second = descriptor.render(b);
            return first > second ? orderFactor : first < second ? -orderFactor : 0;
        });

        this.setState({
            sortField: columnId,
            sortOrder: order
        });
        this.props.onSort(values);
    };

    renderHeader = (id, descriptor) => {
        let order = this.retrieveOrder(id);
        let iconSrc = this.sortIcon.get(order);
        let nextOrder = this.nextOrder(this.retrieveOrder(id));
        return (
            <th key={id} className={descriptor.headStyle}>
                <a href="#" aria-sort={order} onClick={this.sort(id, nextOrder)}>
                    <img src={iconSrc}/>
                    {descriptor.label}
                </a>
            </th>
        );
    };

    render()  {
        return (
            <table>
                Table structure
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

Parent component declares it in next way:

```
<Table structure={this.tableHeader} value={this.state.tableValue} onSort={this.handleChange('tableValue')}
     defaultSortColumn="created" defaultSortOrder={SORT_ORDER.DESC} />
```

The table value is defined in props as `value`. `onSort` is a function that changes the state of the parent component => it changes the table value. Also I have `defaultSortColumn` and `defaultSortOrder` to sort the table after it is filled.

The problem is that my table can be declared multiple times at the page.

So,

1) I'm not able to store the table value in its state. Should I?

2) How can I implement default sorting without using `componentDidMount`? With using current implementation default sorting occurred only once, when `componentDidMount` is invoked, but I have more than 1 `<Table/>` component at the page.
I tried use `componentWillReceiveProps` function, but it is also invoked when I change the `<Table/>` state in `sort` function. So I can't use it.

Comment: I would recommend to use existing solutions for production

Comment: @MartinZinovsky existing solutions do not meet the requirements, because have wrong HTML layout, e.g. div blocks instead of html table etc.

Comment: Which components did you check? I mean there are a lot of them https://react.parts/web?search=table

Comment: @MartinZinovsky I've checked more then 10 different implementations and most of them have wrong HTML layout and all of them don't implement WAI-ARIA standard that we must do. So, I can't use any of existing solutions. However, I can implement the table using one of the existing approach with own layout, but I don't know exactly how. Should I use a component state, or an external function and a parent state, or Redux, or something else? There are too many different implementations and I don't know which is the correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution is:

```
export const SORT_ORDER = {
    ASC: "ascending",
    DESC: "descending",
    OTHER: "other"
};

class TableRow extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                {this.props.children}
            </tr>
        );
    }
}


class TableHeader extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.sortIcon = new Map([
            [SORT_ORDER.ASC, {icon: sortAsc, title: "Ascending"}],
            [SORT_ORDER.DESC, {icon: sortDesc, title: "Descending"}],
            [SORT_ORDER.OTHER, {icon: sortOther, title: "Unsorted"}]
        ]);
    }

    render() {
        const {children, onClick, sortOrder} = this.props;
        return (
            <th>
               {onClick ? (
                <a href="#" aria-sort={sortOrder} onClick={onClick}>
                    <img src={this.sortIcon.get(sortOrder).icon} title={this.sortIcon.get(sortOrder).title} />
                    {children}
                </a>
            ) : children}
            </th>
        );
    }
}

export default class Table extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            sortField: props.defaultSortColumn,
            sortOrder: props.defaultSortOrder
        };
    }

    retrieveOrder = (columnId) => {
        return columnId === this.state.sortField ? this.state.sortOrder : SORT_ORDER.OTHER;
    };

    nextOrder = (current) => {
        if (current === SORT_ORDER.DESC) {
            return SORT_ORDER.ASC;
        } else if (current === SORT_ORDER.ASC) {
            return SORT_ORDER.DESC;
        } else {
            return this.props.defaultSortOrder;
        }
    };

    sortedRows = () => {
        let descriptor = this.props.structure.find(d => d.attribute === this.state.sortField);
        let values = this.props.value.slice();

        let orderFactor = this.state.sortOrder === SORT_ORDER.ASC ? 1 : -1;
        return values.sort((a, b) => {
            let first;
            let second;
            // null and undefined values should be changed to empty string
            if (typeof a[descriptor.attribute] === "number" || typeof b[descriptor.attribute] === "number") {
                first = a[descriptor.attribute] || "";
                second = b[descriptor.attribute] || "";
            } else {
                first = descriptor.render(a) || "";
                second = descriptor.render(b) || "";
            }
            return first > second ? orderFactor : first < second ? -orderFactor : 0;
        });
    };

    renderHeaders = () => {
        return this.props.structure.map((descriptor, id) => {
            let header;
            if (this.props.sortable) {
                const order = this.retrieveOrder(descriptor.attribute);
                const nextOrder = this.nextOrder(order);
                header = (
                    <TableHeader key={id} onClick={() => {this.setState({sortField: descriptor.attribute, sortOrder: nextOrder})}}
                        sortOrder={order}>
                        {descriptor.label}
                    </TableHeader>
                )
            } else {
                header = (
                    <TableHeader key={id}>
                        {descriptor.label}
                    </TableHeader>
                )
            }
            return header;
        });
    };

    renderRows = () => {
        const Row = this.props.customRow || TableRow;
        const values = this.props.sortable ? this.sortedRows() : this.props.value;
        return values.map((value, idx) => (
            <Row key={idx} value={value}>
                {this.props.structure.map((descriptor, id) => (
                    <td key={id}>
                        descriptor.render(value, idx)
                    </td>
                ))}
            </Row>
        ));
    };

    render()  {
        return (
            <table className={this.props.className}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {this.renderHeaders()}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.renderRows()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

Example of the table usage:

```
            this.tableStructure = [
                {
                    attribute: "number", label: "Row Number"
                    render: (row) => {return row.number}
                },
                {
                    attribute: "created", label: "Creation time"
                    render: (row) => {return this.dateToString(row.created)}
                },
                {
                    attribute: "type", label: "Row Type"
                    render: (row) => {return row.type}
                },
                {
                    attribute: "state", label: "State",
                    render: (row) => {return row.state}
                },
                {
                    attribute: "action", label: "Action"
                    render: (row) => {
                            return (
                                <button onClick={this.doSomething}>
                                </button>
                            );
                    }
                }
            ];

            <Table structure={this.tableStructure} value={this.state.someValue} sortable
                                        defaultSortColumn="created" defaultSortOrder={SORT_ORDER.DESC} />
```

The implementation is based on http://styleguide.cfapps.io/react_base_tables.html